# SQLite/GreenDAO session scope

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity, greendao

I'm writing a small application for Android and I'm using GreenDAO as my ORM. I wonder how long should I keep my session open? I have several activities that read/write data from database and I see the following possibilities:

1. Keep session open per Activity basis: created in onCreate and closed onPause/onStop
2. Keep one session open in all activities and just pass it somehow between them.
3. Open session in onCreate, read all the data necessary to populate list view and close while still being in onCreate - I think this forces me to read all the data at once, which can slow down application considerably though.

Which option do you think I should choose? Maybe there's some other, canonical way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a comment to this article:

http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/how-to-get-started/

where "DaoMaster" recommends application scope dao sessions.
He also talks about using Singletons, but I would not recomentd Singletons in Android unless you realy know what you're doing, because Singletons work a little different then on the jvm.